# Why are the colors of certain PNG files getting distorted when opened in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, png, color-profile

I was trying to open an iPhone screenshot in Illustrator, but for some reason the colors are distorted. If I open the same file in any other application (Photoshop, GIMP, Preview, etc.) the colors are rendered fine. The curious thing is that this only occurs with certain screenshots, as I tested a screenshot of the home screen as well, which Illustrator opened without distorting the colors.

Though, with GIMP, a dialog does pop up stating:

> The image 'IMG_1199.PNG' has and embedded color profile:
>
> **Display P3**
>
> Convert the image to the RGB working space (sRGB built-in)?

With the option to either keep or convert the color profile; which makes me think Illustrator may not recognize the aforementioned color profile.

Here is the original image directly from the phone [left] and the image opened (then saved) from Illustrator [right]:

[image: iPhone Keypad Screenshot]
[image: iPhone Keypad Screenshot Distorted]

---

**Update**

Converting the color profile in GIMP, saving, then opening the file again in Illustrator does fix the issue. This seems to confirm my suspicion that the Display P3 color profile is the issue, which changes my question somewhat: how can I open the image in Illustrator without first converting the image beforehand?

This seems like it may be a bug in Illustrator, so I have submitted a bug report to Adobe. I will update if the report is conclusive, or if Adobe provides a solution.

Comment: Psychedelic! I know people who eat pills in order to see this. Hey Bryan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you have any questions about this SE, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat]! Keep contributing and enjoy your time here.

Comment: I've had loads of problems with iPhone screenshots but I've never had anything like that. Impressive.

Comment: Does a P3 color profile imply 10bpp color (aka 30bit)? Is this a bug, or is AI just not able to handle 10bpp (ARGB 02 10 10 10)? Enquiring Minds Want to Know. (edit: to be clear, I really do want to know, as I have no clue)

Comment: Strange: Both, GraphicsMagick's `identify` and Linux' `file`, identify your posted screenshot on the left as a jpg despite its .png suffix. Is this the original/unmodified screenshot? Did you rename the suffix to .png? Maybe that's the problem. Try to change the suffix to jpg and open it again.

Comment: @Socowi Huh, that is strange, I tested it myself using the `file` command on macOS. It comes up as `JPEG image data` as well, even though the info window still displays it as a PNG file. It must be something Imgur does to scale the photos. If you download the image from the [full size link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inh8p.png) the `file` command should recognize it correctly as a PNG file.

Comment: @Bryan You are right. imgur created a jpg thumbnail but did not change the suffix. Thanks for the full size link. I found the problem (but not a solution) and will post it soon.

Comment: Late on this thread but as the issue in Illustrator is still there i wanted to add this. The issue is only on MacOS, witch is strange as its the Apple iOS color profile that acts up. I work in both environments and recently switched from att project on PC with placed PNGs from both iOS and Android. And when i opened the document on my Mac all iOS pngs was distorted. And i found this thread. Relinking the files and even replacing the files gained the same result. Going to report the bug to Adobe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What probably happens: The screenshot is a 16-bit png, but illustrator reads it as an 8-bit png, using only the 8 lower (!) bits.

## Explanation

For the following explanation we assume that the screenshot is a 16-bit grayscale image, that is every pixel is a number between

**black** = 0 = 0x0000 = 0b 0000 0000 0000 0000

and

**(16-bit) white** = 2^16-1 = 65535 = 0xFFFF = 0b 1111 1111 1111 1111.

(0x denotes hexadecimal numbers and 0b denotes binary numbers)

Illustrator seems to load only 8 of these 16 bits, unfortunately the wrong ones, that is the least significant ones. Choosing the least significant bits is the only problem.

```
0b #### #### #### ####
   \_______/ \_______/
   discarded   loaded
```

After the import, illustrator will scale the interpretation (which number is white, which is black) according to the new maximum number:

**(8-bit) white** = 2^8-1 = 255 = 0xFF = 0xb 1111 1111.

Assume one of our pixels had the value 0b 1111 1111 0000 00001 = 0xFF01 = 65281, that is nearly white. After the import, the value will be 0b 0000 0001 = 0x01 = 1, that is nearly black.

It's like "rounding" 999.1 to 1 – completely wrong!

## Simulation

How can we be sure that the described problem is our problem?
We simulate the bug!

The following python program loads the 16-bit screenshot as described above.
(Please don't judge me, it's my very first python program.)

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load picture
img = cv2.imread('screen.png', 3)

# assert (by hand) that picture is loaded as 16 bit image
print img.dtype

# simulate the bug
img[:,:] &= 0x00FF # use only 8 least significant bits
img[:,:] <<= 8     # rescale

# save the picture
cv2.imwrite('bug.png',img)
```

[image: Simulated bug]
the result `bug.png`
Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT6uv.png) for original size, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJUj7.png) to compare with OP's version.

As we can see, our simulation yields exactly the same result.

## Workaround

I only can think of one workaround (since I do not use illustrator):

**Convert your screenshots to 8-bit pngs**

GraphicsMagick and/or ImageMagick are console tools which are convinient for this job. The following command converts to 8-bit pngs:

```
convert original.png -depth 8 converted.png
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the in-depth explanation. Adobe has not responded to my bug report yet, but with any luck hopefully they will add proper 16-bit color support to Illustrator. Or at the very least round them to 8-bit color correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is WAY late, but a simple workaround (for Mac users) is to open the PNG in Preview, then Export it as a PNG switching the default 16-bit option to the 8-bit option. It doesn't require any additional software, and only takes a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Now that is some funky issue.

GIMP already give us some clue, confirming the suspicion that it is something with the color profile of the screenshot.
Converting it your everyday sRGB and 8bit per channel may avoid Illustrator to mess things up on trying to pull it as CMYK.

Answer (score 0):

converting the image to .pdf helped resolve this for me on a mac